# Passing list of Relation object to dbt_utils.union_relation macro fails

Tags: jinja2, dbt

Related to [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) and [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/)

I am using `union_relations` from `dbt_utils` package (0.5.0).

I created my macro which takes list of fully qualified name (like `database.schema.identifier`) splits it and uses `api.Relations.create`  [(link)](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes/#relation) to create a relation and append each relation to a list.

`{{ list_of_relation }}` is given to `dbt_utils.union_relations`(as `relations=my_macro([list of fully qualified names])`), it's giving me an `_is_relation` error, I did use `log` to debug and see if it actually creates a relation and it does. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have a macro written something like this:

```
{% macro my_macro(names) %}
  {% set list_of_relations = [] %}
  {% for name in names %}
    {% set relation = something(name) %}
    {% do list_of_relations.append(relation) %}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ list_of_relations }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Instead of using `{{ list_of_relation }}`, you’ll want `{{ return(list_of_relation) }}` or `{% do return(list_of_relation) %}`. The problem is that `{{ ... }}` turns things into strings in jinja macros, and macros by default return strings.

The documentation on `return` is [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/return/).